# Cant load property in java match-

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, conditional-statements

Trying to implement conditional bean loading in spring. This is the code, problem is, I am not able to load the property inside match method,

```
@Configuration
public class Class implements Condition {

    @Value("${test.property}")
    private boolean testProperty;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, 
                           AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        sout(testProperty);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I can however print the property if I inject it into a constructor, 
but that does not solve my issue, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

For conditional instantiation based on *environment variables* you could use the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation on top of your bean definitions.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "your.property", havingValue = "true")
    public YourBean instantiateIfTrue() {
        // instantiate and return YourBean in case the property is true
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "your.property", havingValue = "false")
    public YourBean instantiateIfFalse() {
        // instantiate and return YourBean in case the property is false
    }

}
```

In your case, you could add the `@ConditionalOnProperty` on top of your `@Configuration` (and no longer extend `Condition`).

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "your.property", havingValue = "true")
public class Config {

    // ...

}
```

Rely on extending `Condition` only if `@ConditionalOnProperty` is not flexible enough for your use case.